# Is there a way to utilize the HttpContextBase function in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm trying to work on the [Microsoft Music Store MVC Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-8). However, I'm unable to proceed due to the "HttpContextBase" method within "ShoppingCart class". Is there a way to utilise the HttpContextBase context in ASP.Net Core5? I understand that the function has been deprecated. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Or if there are better/newer examples of "Shopping Cart with Ajax Updates" that you do not mind sharing, I would love to take a look.

Thank you!

```
public partial class ShoppingCart
{
    MusicStoreEntities storeDB = new MusicStoreEntities();
    string ShoppingCartId { get; set; }
    public const string CartSessionKey = "CartId";
    public static ShoppingCart GetCart(HttpContextBase context)
    {
        var cart = new ShoppingCart();
        cart.ShoppingCartId = cart.GetCartId(context);
        return cart;
    }
```

Comment: Hi, this tutorial is for ASP.NET MVC, not ASP.NET Core MVC, thus You might have some classes unavailable and vice versa. You might want to either create a new project with proper framework for it or go with Core and use HttpContext.Session: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configure-session-state. It would be harder to implement the tutorial though as You will have to fill all the gaps. Best of luck though!

Comment: Hi @Eatos, thank you for pointing it out, will give it a try. Have a great weekend ahead!